# How to use fsolve with multiple variables in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy-optimize

Suppose I have two functions and these libraries

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import sympy as sym

def f19(u, a):
    return (math.sqrt(25 + 26*u + 4*a*u + u**2 + 4*a*u**2 + 4*a**2*u**2) + 2*a*u + u - 5)/(4*a + 6)

def f13(x, u, a, d):    # u, a, d = args[0], args[1], args[2]
    return ((x + 1) ** (a - 1)*x ** ((d*(x + 1) ** a*(x - u)) / u - 1)*(d*x*math.log(x)*(a*(x - u) + x + 1) - d*(x + 1)*(u - x))) / u
```

And a pandas dataframe

```
df = df.sort_values(['u', 'a', 'd', 'k', 'z', 'x_max'], ascending=(True, True, True, True, True, True))
```

Where I want to create some new columns based on the two functions above.

I can get this to work

```
df['x_max19'] = np.vectorize(f19)(df['x_max'], df['a'])
```

But I don't know the syntax for using a function that uses fsolve with variables from the dataframe.

```
k_t = math.log(0.55 + 2*df['u'])/df['u']
df['x_max13'] = .... fsolve(f13, k_t)[0].real
```

I've tried np.vectorize, df.apply, and mixes of both.

df['x_max1'] = fsolve(np.vectorize(f13)(x, [df['u'], df['a'], df['d']]), k_t)  # eg

I get this error:

```
    u, a, d = args[0], args[1], args[2]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

When I use things like:

```
df['x_max1'] = df.apply(fsolve(f13, k_t), axis=1)
```

I get this error

```
k_t = math.log(0.55 + 2*df['u'])/df['u']
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

If possible I'd like to use my existing mathematical notation in my formulas so I don't have to re-write all my formulas as vectors.

Comment: Change your functions to vectorised versions thereof. Eg, try `np.log` instead of `math.log`

Comment: How do I write the rest of it?
df['x_max1'] = np.vectorize(fsolve(f13,x0=k_t)(df['u'], df['a'], df['d']))
returns:
TypeError: f13() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'u', 'a', and 'd'

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem